# Do weed something to sync elasticsearch dsl to postgres databse

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, e-commerce, elasticsearch-dsl

Actually we are deploying elasticsearch django application in aws ec2.Here, i need to know something about elasticsearch. Will elasticearch automatically updates with the update in postgres or do we need to use extra modules to sync elasticsearch and postgres together so that whatever changes happens in postgres database, it will also update in elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch-dsl keeps sync between indexes and db